# Installing libsdl2-dev on Kali 3.18.0 amd64

Tags: debian, package-management, kali-linux, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to install the libsdl2-dev package on Kali 3.18.0 amd64.

I can see that the package is available in the standard Kali repository here: http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/libs/libsdl2/, but I can't seem to get apt-get to install it along with its dependencies. Here is some of the output that I'm getting:

"sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev" yields:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-dev
```

"sudo apt-cache search libsdl2" yields nothing, while "sudo apt-cache search libsdl" yields a bunch of libsdl1.2 packages (I need libsdl2).

I'm using apt-get update before trying any installations. My sources.list file contains the following repositories:

```
deb http://security.kali.org/ kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/ kali/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Other things I've tried:

- Adding the bleeding-edge repo 
  "deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge main contrib non-free"
- Downloading the package itself and using dpkg -i (doesn't work as there are lots of dependencies missing)

I'm thinking that my last resort would be to manually download all of the dependencies and use dpkg -i on all of them so that the apt-get install command doesn't complain. There has to be a more graceful way to do this though (and there's definitely some knowledge gap that I have with the package manager).

Is the package being ignored by apt because of incompatibilities with my distro version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev` ? What errors do you get? Have you done `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am indeed updating before trying to install the packages. Going to edit the question to add output from the commands.

Answer (score 0):

My sources.list looks like this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160120-18:14]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160120-18:14]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

I downloaded the DEB from the first link on the list you linked and then dpkg'ed it and it went flawlessly. You could try upgrading to Kali rolling release.